# MySQL tuning: INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE not found?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, aurora

My replicator MySQL db, hosted by Amazon-RDS-Aurora is performing poorly. The DB is quite powerful so performance shouldn't be an issue.

When I executed

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

I could not find INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE. How could this be? I suspect this parameter is related to the poor performance.

Here are my config variables:

- Variable_name Value
- aurora_lab_mode  OFF
- aurora_load_from_s3_role
- aurora_max_alter_table_log_entries   1000
- aurora_max_connections_limit 16000
- aurora_select_into_s3_role
- aurora_server_id tableau
- aurora_use_key_prefetch  ON
- aurora_version   1.17.2
- auto_increment_increment 1
- auto_increment_offset    1
- autocommit   ON
- automatic_sp_privileges  ON
- aws_default_lambda_role
- aws_default_s3_role
- awsauthenticationplugin_max_backoff_delay    2000
- awsauthenticationplugin_max_retry_count  3
- awsauthenticationplugin_retry_delay  250
- back_log 650
- basedir  /rdsdbbin/oscar/
- big_tables   OFF
- bind_address *
- binlog_cache_size    32768
- binlog_checksum  CRC32
- binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates  OFF
- binlog_format    STATEMENT
- binlog_max_flush_queue_time  0
- binlog_order_commits ON
- binlog_row_image FULL
- binlog_rows_query_log_events OFF
- binlog_stmt_cache_size   32768
- bulk_insert_buffer_size  8388608
- character_set_client utf8
- character_set_connection utf8
- character_set_database   latin1
- character_set_filesystem binary
- character_set_results    utf8
- character_set_server latin1
- character_set_system utf8
- character_sets_dir   *
- collation_connection utf8_general_ci
- collation_database   latin1_swedish_ci
- collation_server latin1_swedish_ci
- completion_type  NO_CHAIN
- concurrent_insert    AUTO
- connect_timeout  10
- core_file    ON
- datadir  /rdsdbdata/db/
- date_format  %Y-%m-%d
- datetime_format  %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
- default_storage_engine   InnoDB
- default_tmp_storage_engine   InnoDB
- default_week_format  0
- delay_key_write  ON
- delayed_insert_limit 100
- delayed_insert_timeout   300
- delayed_queue_size   1000
- disconnect_on_expired_password   ON
- div_precision_increment  4
- end_markers_in_json  OFF
- enforce_gtid_consistency OFF
- eq_range_index_dive_limit    10
- error_count  0
- event_scheduler  OFF
- expire_logs_days 0
- explicit_defaults_for_timestamp  ON
- external_user
- flush    OFF
- flush_time   0
- foreign_key_checks   ON
- ft_boolean_syntax    + -><()~*:\"&|"
- ft_max_word_len  84
- ft_min_word_len  4
- ft_query_expansion_limit 20
- ft_stopword_file (built-in)
- general_log  OFF
- general_log_file /rdsdbdata/log/general/mysql-general.log
- group_concat_max_len 1024
- gtid_executed
- gtid_mode    OFF
- gtid_next    AUTOMATIC
- gtid_owned
- gtid_purged
- have_compress    YES
- have_crypt   YES
- have_dynamic_loading YES
- have_geometry    YES
- have_openssl YES
- have_profiling   YES
- have_query_cache YES
- have_rtree_keys  YES
- have_ssl YES
- have_symlink YES
- host_cache_size  128
- hostname ip-10-1-1-83
- identity 0
- ignore_builtin_innodb    OFF
- ignore_db_dirs
- ignore_default_storage_engine_errors OFF
- init_connect
- init_file
- init_slave
- innodb_adaptive_flushing ON
- innodb_adaptive_flushing_lwm 10
- innodb_adaptive_hash_index   OFF
- innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay  150000
- innodb_additional_mem_pool_size  8388608
- innodb_api_bk_commit_interval    5
- innodb_api_disable_rowlock   OFF
- innodb_api_enable_binlog OFF
- innodb_api_enable_mdl    OFF
- innodb_api_trx_level 0
- innodb_aurora_enable_auto_akp    OFF
- innodb_autoextend_increment  64
- innodb_autoinc_lock_mode 1
- innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown  OFF
- innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now  OFF
- innodb_buffer_pool_filename  ib_buffer_pool
- innodb_buffer_pool_instances 8
- innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort    OFF
- innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup   OFF
- innodb_buffer_pool_load_now  OFF
- innodb_change_buffer_max_size    25
- innodb_change_buffering  none
- innodb_checksum_algorithm    none
- innodb_checksums OFF
- innodb_cmp_per_index_enabled OFF
- innodb_commit_concurrency    0
- innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct 5
- innodb_compression_level 6
- innodb_compression_pad_pct_max   50
- innodb_concurrency_tickets   5000
- innodb_data_file_path    ibdata1:12M:autoextend
- innodb_data_home_dir
- innodb_disable_sort_file_cache   OFF
- innodb_doublewrite   OFF
- innodb_fast_shutdown 1
- innodb_file_format   Antelope
- innodb_file_format_check ON
- innodb_file_format_max   Antelope
- innodb_file_per_table    ON
- innodb_flush_log_at_timeout  1
- innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit   1
- innodb_flush_method  O_DIRECT
- innodb_flush_neighbors   1
- innodb_flushing_avg_loops    30
- innodb_force_load_corrupted  OFF
- innodb_force_recovery    0
- innodb_ft_aux_table
- innodb_ft_cache_size 8000000
- innodb_ft_enable_diag_print  OFF
- innodb_ft_enable_stopword    ON
- innodb_ft_max_token_size 84
- innodb_ft_min_token_size 3
- innodb_ft_num_word_optimize  2000
- innodb_ft_result_cache_limit 2000000000
- innodb_ft_server_stopword_table
- innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree    2
- innodb_ft_total_cache_size   640000000
- innodb_ft_user_stopword_table
- innodb_io_capacity   200
- innodb_io_capacity_max   2000
- innodb_large_prefix  OFF
- innodb_lock_wait_timeout 50
- innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog   OFF
- innodb_log_buffer_size   8388608
- innodb_log_file_size 50331648
- innodb_log_files_in_group    2
- innodb_log_group_home_dir    ./
- innodb_lru_scan_depth    1024
- innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct   75
- innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct_lwm   0
- innodb_max_purge_lag 0
- innodb_max_purge_lag_delay   0
- innodb_mirrored_log_groups   1
- innodb_monitor_disable
- innodb_monitor_enable
- innodb_monitor_reset
- innodb_monitor_reset_all
- innodb_old_blocks_pct    37
- innodb_old_blocks_time   1000
- innodb_online_alter_log_max_size 134217728
- innodb_open_files    6000
- innodb_optimize_fulltext_only    OFF
- innodb_page_size 16384
- innodb_print_all_deadlocks   OFF
- innodb_purge_batch_size  900
- innodb_purge_threads 3
- innodb_random_read_ahead OFF
- innodb_read_ahead_threshold  56
- innodb_read_io_threads   16
- innodb_read_only OFF
- innodb_replication_delay 0
- innodb_rollback_on_timeout   OFF
- innodb_rollback_segments 128
- innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages    ON
- innodb_sort_buffer_size  1048576
- innodb_spin_wait_delay   6
- innodb_stats_auto_recalc ON
- innodb_stats_method  nulls_equal
- innodb_stats_on_metadata OFF
- innodb_stats_persistent  ON
- innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages 20
- innodb_stats_sample_pages    8
- innodb_stats_transient_sample_pages  8
- innodb_strict_mode   OFF
- innodb_support_xa    ON
- innodb_sync_array_size   1
- innodb_sync_spin_loops   30
- innodb_table_locks   ON
- innodb_thread_concurrency    0
- innodb_thread_sleep_delay    10000
- innodb_undo_directory    .
- innodb_undo_logs 128
- innodb_undo_tablespaces  0
- innodb_use_native_aio    OFF
- innodb_use_sys_malloc    ON
- innodb_version   1.2.10
- innodb_write_io_threads  4
- insert_id    0
- interactive_timeout  28800
- join_buffer_size 262144
- keep_files_on_create OFF
- key_buffer_size  16777216
- key_cache_age_threshold  300
- key_cache_block_size 1024
- key_cache_division_limit 100
- large_files_support  ON
- large_page_size  0
- large_pages  OFF
- last_insert_id   0
- lc_messages  en_US
- lc_messages_dir  /rdsdbbin/oscar-5.6.10a.200116.0/share/
- lc_time_names    en_US
- license  GPL
- local_infile ON
- lock_wait_timeout    31536000
- locked_in_memory OFF
- log_bin  OFF
- log_bin_basename
- log_bin_index
- log_bin_trust_function_creators  OFF
- log_bin_use_v1_row_events    OFF
- log_error    /rdsdbdata/log/error/mysql-error.log
- log_output   TABLE
- log_queries_not_using_indexes    OFF
- log_slave_updates    ON
- log_throttle_queries_not_using_indexes   0
- log_warnings 1
- long_query_time  10
- low_priority_updates OFF
- lower_case_file_system   OFF
- lower_case_table_names   0
- master_info_repository   TABLE
- master_verify_checksum   OFF
- max_allowed_packet   4194304
- max_binlog_cache_size    1.84467E+19
- max_binlog_size  134217728
- max_binlog_stmt_cache_size   1.84467E+19
- max_connect_errors   100
- max_connections  3000
- max_delayed_threads  20
- max_digest_length    1024
- max_error_count  64
- max_heap_table_size  16777216
- max_insert_delayed_threads   20
- max_join_size    1.84467E+19
- max_length_for_sort_data 1024
- max_prepared_stmt_count  16382
- max_relay_log_size   0
- max_seeks_for_key    1.84467E+19
- max_sort_length  1024
- max_sp_recursion_depth   0
- max_tmp_tables   32
- max_user_connections 0
- max_write_lock_count 1.84467E+19
- metadata_locks_cache_size    1024
- min_examined_row_limit   0
- multi_range_count    256
- myisam_data_pointer_size 6
- myisam_max_sort_file_size    9.22337E+18
- myisam_mmap_size 1.84467E+19
- myisam_recover_options   OFF
- myisam_repair_threads    1
- myisam_sort_buffer_size  8388608
- myisam_stats_method  nulls_unequal
- myisam_use_mmap  OFF
- net_buffer_length    16384
- net_read_timeout 30
- net_retry_count  10
- net_write_timeout    60
- new  OFF
- old  OFF
- old_alter_table  OFF
- old_passwords    0
- open_files_limit 65535
- optimizer_prune_level    1
- optimizer_search_depth   62
- optimizer_switch index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,engine_condition_pushdown=on,index_condition_pushdown=on,mrr=on,mrr_cost_based=on,block_nested_loop=on,batched_key_access=off,materialization=on,semijoin=on,loosescan=on,firstmatch=on,subquery_materialization_cost_based=on,use_index_extensions=on,hash_join=on,hash_join_cost_based=on
- optimizer_trace  enabled=off,one_line=off
- optimizer_trace_features greedy_search=on,range_optimizer=on,dynamic_range=on,repeated_subselect=on
- optimizer_trace_limit    1
- optimizer_trace_max_mem_size 16384
- optimizer_trace_offset   -1
- performance_schema   OFF
- performance_schema__auto__   ON
- performance_schema_accounts_size 100
- performance_schema_digests_size  10000
- performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size   10000
- performance_schema_events_stages_history_size    10
- performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size   10000
- performance_schema_events_statements_history_size    10
- performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size    10000
- performance_schema_events_waits_history_size 10
- performance_schema_hosts_size    100
- performance_schema_max_cond_classes  80
- performance_schema_max_cond_instances    52160
- performance_schema_max_digest_length 1024
- performance_schema_max_file_classes  50
- performance_schema_max_file_handles  32768
- performance_schema_max_file_instances    92616
- performance_schema_max_mutex_classes 200
- performance_schema_max_mutex_instances   319090
- performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes    40
- performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances  126430
- performance_schema_max_socket_classes    10
- performance_schema_max_socket_instances  6050
- performance_schema_max_stage_classes 150
- performance_schema_max_statement_classes 177
- performance_schema_max_table_handles 12000
- performance_schema_max_table_instances   25000
- performance_schema_max_thread_classes    50
- performance_schema_max_thread_instances  6130
- performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size    512
- performance_schema_setup_actors_size 100
- performance_schema_setup_objects_size    100
- performance_schema_users_size    100
- pid_file /rdsdbdata/log/mysql-3306.pid
- plugin_dir   /rdsdbbin/oscar-5.6.10a.200116.0/lib/plugin/
- port 3306
- preload_buffer_size  32768
- profiling    OFF
- profiling_history_size   15
- protocol_version 10
- proxy_user
- pseudo_slave_mode    OFF
- pseudo_thread_id 46502
- query_alloc_block_size   8192
- query_cache_limit    1048576
- query_cache_min_res_unit 4096
- query_cache_size 2459388928
- query_cache_type ON
- query_cache_wlock_invalidate OFF
- query_prealloc_size  8192
- rand_seed1   0
- rand_seed2   0
- range_alloc_block_size   4096
- read_buffer_size 262144
- read_only    OFF
- read_rnd_buffer_size 524288
- relay_log    /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
- relay_log_basename   /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog
- relay_log_index  /rdsdbdata/log/relaylog/relaylog.index
- relay_log_info_file  relay-log.info
- relay_log_info_repository    TABLE
- relay_log_purge  ON
- relay_log_recovery   ON
- relay_log_space_limit    1000000000
- report_host
- report_password
- report_port  3306
- report_user
- require_fk_checks_for_ddl    OFF
- rpl_stop_slave_timeout   31536000
- secure_auth  ON
- secure_file_priv /tmp/
- server_audit_cw_upload   OFF
- server_audit_events
- server_audit_excl_users
- server_audit_incl_users
- server_audit_logging OFF
- server_audit_mode    0
- server_audit_query_log_limit 1024
- server_id    *
- server_id_bits   32
- server_uuid  *
- sha256_password_private_key_path private_key.pem
- sha256_password_public_key_path  public_key.pem
- skip_external_locking    ON
- skip_name_resolve    ON
- skip_networking  OFF
- skip_show_database   OFF
- slave_allow_batching OFF
- slave_checkpoint_group   512
- slave_checkpoint_period  300
- slave_compressed_protocol    OFF
- slave_exec_mode  STRICT
- slave_load_tmpdir    /rdsdbdata/tmp/
- slave_max_allowed_packet 1073741824
- slave_net_timeout    3600
- slave_parallel_workers   0
- slave_pending_jobs_size_max  16777216
- slave_rows_search_algorithms TABLE_SCAN,INDEX_SCAN
- slave_skip_errors    OFF
- slave_sql_verify_checksum    ON
- slave_transaction_retries    10
- slave_type_conversions
- slow_launch_time 2
- slow_query_log   OFF
- slow_query_log_file  /rdsdbdata/log/slowquery/mysql-slowquery.log
- socket   /tmp/mysql.sock
- sort_buffer_size 262144
- sql_auto_is_null OFF
- sql_big_selects  ON
- sql_buffer_result    OFF
- sql_log_bin  ON
- sql_log_off  OFF
- sql_mode
- sql_notes    ON
- sql_quote_show_create    ON
- sql_safe_updates OFF
- sql_select_limit 1.84467E+19
- sql_slave_skip_counter   0
- sql_warnings OFF
- ssl_ca   /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/ca-cert.pem
- ssl_capath
- ssl_cert /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-cert.pem
- ssl_cipher   *
- ssl_crl
- ssl_crlpath
- ssl_key  /rdsdbdata/rds-metadata/server-key.pem
- storage_engine   InnoDB
- stored_program_cache 256
- sync_binlog  1
- sync_frm ON
- sync_master_info 10000
- sync_relay_log   10000
- sync_relay_log_info  10000
- system_time_zone UTC
- table_definition_cache   20000
- table_open_cache 6000
- table_open_cache_instances   16
- thread_cache_size    58
- thread_concurrency   10
- thread_handling  multiple-connections-per-thread
- thread_stack 262144
- time_format  %H:%i:%s
- time_zone    SYSTEM
- timed_mutexes    OFF
- timestamp    1531841565
- tmp_table_size   16777216
- tmpdir   /rdsdbdata/tmp/
- transaction_alloc_block_size 8192
- transaction_allow_batching   OFF
- transaction_prealloc_size    4096
- tx_isolation REPEATABLE-READ
- tx_read_only OFF
- unique_checks    ON
- updatable_views_with_limit   YES
- user_disable_external_log    OFF
- version  5.6.10
- version_comment  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- version_compile_machine  x86_64
- version_compile_os   Linux
- wait_timeout 28800
- warning_count    0

---

Comment: Unexpected.  I also see `innodb_version 1.2.10`.  Raise the question with Amazon support.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is not there.

Even if you could manipulate its value, best practices for Aurora says you should leave it alone. Please notice what the [Best Practices Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-amazon-aurora-mysql-database-configuration/) says under the subheading `Default parameter values and their importance`:

> Certain DB instance parameters contain variables or formulas, in which
>   the value is determined by constants. Examples are the instance’s size
>   and memory footprint, network port for the instance, and its allocated
>   storage. It’s best to leave these unchanged, as they adjust
>   automatically whenever an instance scale-up or down operation is
>   performed.
>
> For example, Aurora DB parameter innodb_buffer_pool_size defaults to:
>
> ```
> {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}
> ```
>
> DBInstanceClassMemory is a variable that
>   is set to your instance’s memory size in GiB.
>
> Example: For a db.r4.xlarge instance with 30.5 GiB of memory, this
>   value is 20,090,716,160 bytes or 18.71 GiB.
>
> Suppose that we decide to set this parameter to a fixed value, say to
>   18,000,000,000 bytes, and later we run a scale-down operation to
>   db.r4.large, which has half as much memory (15.2 GiB). In this case,
>   we will likely then encounter an out-of-memory condition on the
>   database engine after modifying it, and the instance can’t properly
>   start.

[Since MySQL 5.7 allows a user with SUPER privilege to dynamically resize the Buffer Pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size), there is no point to setting it to a fixed value. Just let Amazon deal with it. This gives Aurora the edge over RDS with a Buffer Pool that scale with memory supply-and-demand.

I am aware the question is tagged with `mysql-5.6`. This means the InnoDB Buffer Pool cannot be resized dynamically (requires a restart of the instance to take effect). The principle I mentioned for MySQL 5.7 still applies so that changing [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) would amount to changing the Instance Class. Memory needs would still be met without endangering the Instance to OOM conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES like 'INNODB_BUFFER%';
```

Another way is to select the variable:

```
select @@INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE;
```

Comment: @ColinMac  How much RAM is on the replication server?  Suggestion to consider for my.cnf [mysqld] section 

innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 to conserve CPU every second and  max_connections=reasonable limit # from 3000 to conserve RAM.  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'max_used_connections' to get an idea of a more reasonable number.  Please view my profile, Network Profile for contact info and to get FREE My Top 10 Global Variable Suggestions for your specific server.